# Vectorize a for loop to fill row

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization, nested-loops

I attempted to vectorize the following:

```
for i = 2:n
    mat = NaN(m,i);
    for j = 1:m
        mat(j,:) = getVal(i);
    end
    num(i) = max(mat(:));
end
```

into

```
for i = 2:n
    mat = NaN(m,i);
    j = 1:m;
    mat(j,:) = getVal(i);
    num(i) = max(mat(:));
end
```

But, MATLAB is giving me an error: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" I'm not sure where my code went wrong?

Also, is it possible to vectorize the whole nested for loop, instead of just the inner loop?

Thanks!

**Edit:** My apologies, the function `getVal()` returns a random vector of size 'i'. This is used to fill the matrix's rows in the code provided, hence this post's question title "Vectorize a for loop to fill row". Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Sample Data:
For i = 2, the output would be as follows:
[Matrix Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sorLa.jpg) The rows of the matrix are filled one at a time in the inner loop.
For i = 3, it'd be the same as above, with 3 columns instead:
[Matrix Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwiz6.jpg)

Hope that's clear?

**Edit 2:** I've just tried using `repmat` as advised by Cris Luengo's solution. This is my output: [Matrix Output with repmat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqLmG.jpg). I need the function getVal to be run each time, instead of simply running it once and copying its contents down the rows.

**Edit 3:** Alright, here is my function getVal(i):

```
function [A] = getVal(m)
    X = normrnd(0,1,[m,m]);
    A = triu(X) + triu(X)';
    A = A - diag(diag(A))/2;
    A = eig(A)';
end
```

Comment: ***1.*** Please provide some sample data to run your loops. ***2.*** Is `getVal` a matrix? is it a function? What is it? Please provide a [MCVE]. ***3.*** Please explain what your loops do.

Comment: Apologies! Just updated it! @SardarUsama

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, you're right. I seem to have misunderstood the concept of vectorization, and naively thought it'd speed up the process. I uploaded the function if it helps.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry, I've fixed it. It's running fine, just missed the last line.

Comment: @StaticCrazee: `eig` makes it difficult to vectorize. There is [this FileExchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27680-multiple-eigen-values-for-2x2-and-3x3-matrices) that vectorizes the `eig` computation but only for 2x2 or 3x3 matrices. I don't know how to vectorize your code. But your question is complete now, so I'm reversing my downvote.

Comment: Thank you @CrisLuengo. You're very patient :) I'll have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your examples, getVal(i) doesn't keep returning same outputs for repeated calls to it. As I don't have your code, I simulated that behaviour using:

```
function out = getVal(i)
   out = rand(1, i);
end
```

Now, if you cannot touch getVal but want to have everything vectorized, I would use `arrayfun` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)

```
mat = cell2mat(arrayfun(@getVal, repmat(i, m, 1), 'UniformOutput', false)); % UniformOutput is needed because output isn't a scalar. Cell2mat is used to convert to the same matrix as previously.
```

The rest of your code is the same. Note that everything works as before, you just don't have loops.

But you still have the outer loop. Another arrayfun handles that:

```
num = arrayfun(@(i, m) max(max(cell2mat(arrayfun(@getVal, repmat(i, m, 1), 'UniformOutput', false)))), 1:n, repmat(m, 1, n));
```

Note that this does not calculate `mat`, but I assume it isn't really needed given it keeps getting rewritten for every `i`.

**But ... it isn't faster**. I timed this with n=1000, m=1000 and your code with 2 loops gives me 7.3s, the first vectorized approach is done in 10.8s and the final one is done in 10.7s, and again the 2 loop approach ends in 7.1s this time.

The obvious step to really speed up the code is to vectorize getVal - something I cannot help you with, as long as I have no idea what exactly it does. But if this upper rand approach gets done in about 5s if it returns the whole mat in a single step.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, Zizy!

Comment: `arrayfun` uses a loop internally, there is no point in using it in this case. You add a level of indirection with the function handle, hence the additional cost. This code is more difficult to read than the OP's, and hence worse, even if the timing were equal. Writing a 3-statement program on a single line is not vectorizing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That's true. Is there a way to vectorize it though?

Comment: @StaticCrazee: If your code is too slow, show us `getVal` (if you can). That is the function that needs to be vectorized. Your double loop is fine, you can't speed it up. The cost is in calling `getVal`.